# non-static method basemodel::validate() should not be called statically,assuming $this from compatible context

Tags: laravel

Was tryin to validate my registration form calling the validation method from the basemodel in my controller
The method

```
  public function postSIgnup () 
  {
        $validation = User::validate(Input::all());
  }
```

Routes

Route::post('register', array('before=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UsersController@postSignup'));

Help mi solve this problem

Comment: What error? Can you provide us some more code?
Add you blade template please and your route.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say 'validate my whole form'. 
The reason this error occurs is because you are trying to use the validation method from Laravel.

**Basic Form Validation in Laravel**

First you want to grab all your form data/content.

```
$input = Input::all();
```

Secondly you can setup some rules. Those rules can be set in an array which Laravel will use.
Make sure the names are correctly spelled. (Those are the ones u used in your form-template.)

```
$rules = array(
            'real_name' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:80|Alpha',
            'email'     => 'Required|Between:3,64|Email|Unique:users',
            'age'       => 'Integer|Min:18',
            'password'  =>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:4,8|Confirmed',
            'password_confirmation'=>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:4,8'
    );
```

To make use of the validator you have to create anew instance first: 
You attach the form input and the rules you have set above.
When they match you can save your form to your database or what else you would like to do with it. That will probably look like:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input,$rules);
```

Cool,
We can check now if the Validator passes or not...

```
if($validator->fails()){
 $messages = $validator->messages();
 return Redirect::to('yourpage')->withErrors($messages);
}else{
 // Handle your data... 
}
```